# Total.js CMS export all complete pages to folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-management-system, total.js, nosql

I'm using Total.js CMS for my blog, but I want to export the complete HTML files from the database

I tried this code to export it

```
NOSQL('pages').find().callback(function(err, response) {
      response.forEach(function(page) {
            fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/content/index.html', page.body);
      });
});
```

But it only rendered the widgets that I'm using, not the full page.

How to do it properly? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better solution. Create a definition file e.g. `export` and run your CMS. All pages will be stored in `/public/render/` directory.

```js
const Fs = require('fs');

function save() {
    NOSQL('pages').find().fields('id').callback(function(err, response) {
        var repository = {};
        var filter = {};
        var directory = F.path.public('/render/');
        try {
            Fs.mkdirSync(directory);
        } catch (e) {}
        response.waitFor(function(item, next) {
            filter.id = item.id;
            GETSCHEMA('Page').operation('render', filter, function(err, response) {
                repository.cms = true;
                repository.render = true;
                repository.page = response;
                Fs.writeFile(directory + response.title.slug() + '.html', F.view('~/cms/' + response.template, EMPTYOBJECT, '~/cms/layout', repository), next);
            });
        }, () => console.log('DONE'));
    });
}

F.on('ready', save);
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, Peter!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are overwriting index.html but you need each page to go into its own file. But that still doesn't fix the issue you have since the `page.body` is rendered into `./themes/default/views/cms/default.html` template which is rendered into `./themes/default/views/layout.html`

Bellow code might do what you need:

```
NOSQL('pages').find().callback(function(err, response) {
      response.forEach(function(page) {
            fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/content/' + page.id + '.html', F.view('~/cms/default', {}, { page: { body: page.body }}));
      });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution, Molda!